# что это значит и как исправить?

Tags: node.js

```
Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\....\mdb.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:485:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:437:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:605:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:158:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:575:3
```

Comment: уточните вопрос: команда запуска, конфиги package.json, gulp откуда этот результат.

Answer (score 0):

Вы неправильно указали путь до модуля в команде

```
require('./');
```

на строке 575 в файле `bootstrap_node`
Без кода деталей не будет